# Why I get This error? Can't Load Types From

Tags: c#, android, ios, xaml, xamarin

I was in my project and suddenly, this error appeared:
`Can't load types from xmlns http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/   xaml/presentation    TaskX.UWP   C:\Users\M\source\repos\TaskX\TaskX\TaskX\New.xaml`

This is my full code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage

x:Class="TaskX.New"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TaskX"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">

<StackLayout>
  <Label Text="Hello World"/>
</StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: `I was in my project and suddenly, this error appeared:` At compile time? Run time? Does https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/98377/uwp-cant-load-types-from-xmlns-http-schemas-microsoft-com-winfx-2006-xaml-presentation help?

Comment: have you tried to rename the class or something?

Comment: @TheGeneral Yeah, For a moment worked, but then it still

Comment: What did you rename it

Comment: @TheGeneral It was New, now I change the file name and the class name to Newpage

Answer (score 1):

If you are renaming pages, you need to make sure the xaml class is pointing to your backing class

**Xaml**

```
<ContentPage
    x:Class="YourNameSpace.SomeAwesomeNamePage"
```

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class SomeAwesomeNamePage : ContentPage
```

Comment: @GerardoMartinez May i suggest creating a new Page it will be quicker, just start again. and then compare the diffrence